# Constructing a function with saddle points

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Construct a function $f:R^2 \to R$ whose saddle points are given by ${(n, 2m + 1 - n | n \in Z, m \in Z}$ where $Z$ is the set of integers.

The conditions should be ${\partial f(x,y) \over \partial x} = {\partial f(x,y) \over \partial y} = 0$, and Hessian matrix should be negative, but I think it has too little information and found it difficult to solve this problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Here's a function with saddle points at each integer point on the $x$-axis:
$$
g(x, y) = \cos(2\pi x) + y^2.
$$

If I write
$$
h(x, y) = g(x/2, y)
$$
then $h$ would have saddles at each *even* integer point of the $x$-axis. Can you use this to work out something similar for your problem?